# How do I properly redirect requests to Wordpress subdirectory?

Tags: htaccess, php

Still learning things with Wordpress installation. Was trying to follow this [guide](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/) to redirect from `public_html` to `wp` so that visitors don't see the page displaying available folders.

I'm not totally sure where I went wrong, but I may have put the **Wordpress address** and **Site address** in reverse order on steps 3 and 4 while working on the setup.

It threw some kind of error when I pressed update (didn't catch it or I would have posted it.)
Now my site is loading incompletely, with parts of the theme displaying. I am unable to log in and getting the following redirect:

`http://www.example.com/wp/wp-admin` -> `http://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwp%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1` with a "Page not found" (presumably the 404 page).

My current directory looks like:

```
public_html
 |->.well-known
 |->cgi-bin
 |->example.com
 |->wp
 |.htaccess
 |favicon.ico
 |index.php
```

Where `example.com` is an unused FTP folder, and `wp` is the Wordpress install directory.

`.htaccess` reads:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

`index.php` reads:

```
 <?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/wp/wp-blog-header.php';
```

No other files have been subject to editing. Removing these two files bring back some functionality to the main page but most of the styling and images are not loading properly. `example.com/wp/wp-admin`and `example.com/wp-admin` remain 404'd in this state.

I don't have shell access on this host. If you're writing an `.htaccess` change out, please spell out what you're doing for someone who's not super familiar, and make sure it's secure.

Comment: Why is WordPress in the `wp` directory?  If you want to run WordPress on the whole site (not in a subdirectory) you would usually install it directly in the document root.

Comment: It leaves space if I ever want to put up another web app (i.e. something I code in Laravel) on the server. Learning to manage m`.htacces` and other parts of making a multi-install site work are one thing I need to grow on in server administration.